# Set text in the textfield does not work in Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, text, properties, set

I would like to set an text in the text field in another class and get it from another class. This is something what I want, but it does not work. Can you please help me. Thank you!

**aaa.h**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface aaa : NSImageView {
    IBOutlet NSTextField *message;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSTextField *message;
@end
```

**aaa.m**

```
#import "aaa.h"
#import "bbb.h"

@implementation aaa
@synthesize message;

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // [message setStringValue:@"ok, this works!"]; //but i don't want it from here
    [self hello];
}
@end
```

**bbb.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSObject (bbb)
- (void)hello;
@end
```

**bbb.m**

```
#import "bbb.h"
#import "aaa.h"

@implementation NSObject (bbb)
- (void)hello {
    aaa *obj = [[[aaa alloc] init] autorelease];
    [obj.message setStringValue:@"This doesn't work :("]; // set text here, dont work.
    NSLog(@"TEST: %@", [obj.message stringValue]);
}
@end
```

Comment: seems like at [obj.message setStringValue:...] your message property == nil (because it not awaked from nib), could you check this?

Comment: i checked it is nil and how can i awake it? i am still in learn process.

Comment: You have nothing to create the NSTextField object for message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using category, so first thing it is used for extending the functionality of existing class. So you cannot set textfield value inside category. But else you can add some functonality after extracting the value. So you have to pass the value inside the category first. Try like this below:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    NSString *resultString=[self hello:@"This doesn't work :("];
[message setStringValue:resultString];
}
@end


@interface NSObject (bbb)
- (NSString*)hello:(NSString*)yourString;
@end

@implementation NSObject (bbb)
- (NSString*)hello:(NSString*)yourString {
    return yourString;
}
@end
```

Comment: You gave me the exact answer that i have searched for about what the category can and what not. Thank you very much!